# Sort by given formula (Haversine) with Query DSL

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I have `latitude` and `longitude` in my `Location` enitity. Now im using something like that to get nearest locations by given coords.

```
String haversine = "(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(" +
        "POWER(SIN((l.latitude - ?1) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +" +
        "COS(l.latitude * pi()/180) * COS(?1 * pi()/180) *" +
        "POWER(SIN((l.longitude - ?2) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )))";

@Query(value = "SELECT l FROM Location l ORDER BY " + haversine)
List<Location> findNearest(String latitude, String longitude);
```

But now I want to customize this query with Query DSL. I'm trying to find out how to sort records by given formula and values from entity, using [`OrderSpecifier<?>`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.3.2/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/OrderSpecifier.html)

Maybe I should create method in my `Location` entity which returns me distance between place and given coords. But I think creating method in MODEL layer is not the best approach for this problem.

So my main question is: how to sort records by given formula (eg Haversine) in Query DSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) from [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) and code looks like this.

```
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Place.class).get();

    Double centerLatitude = 51d;
    Double centerLongitude = 17d;
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder
            .spatial()
            .within(1000, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(centerLatitude)
            .andLongitude(centerLongitude)
            .createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Place.class);

    em.close();
    return (List<Place>) jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, `haversine` is just a formula (i.e. a function) with 2 parameters latitude and longitude. Indeed creating methods inside a model isn't the best approach. You should instead have a `LocationService` class with `@Service` (if you're using Spring or Springboot) which contains all of your program's logic. Inside there you can have a function for calculating with distance and THEN pass it onto your function that uses `QueryDSL` for the ordering.

Something like this:

```
public class Location {
  private int latitude;
  private int longitude;
}

@Service
public class LocationServices {

  public String haversineCalculation(int locationLat, int locationLong, int latitude, int longitude) {
    //Do your calculations here in java
  }

  public List<Location> findNearest(int latitude, int longitude) {
    QLocation location = QLocation.location;
    SQLTemplates dialect = new YourSQLDialectTemplate();
    SQLQuery query = new SQLQueryImpl(connection, dialect);
    List<Location> locations = query
      .from(location);
    locations.sort((loc1, loc2) -> haversineCalculation(loc1.latitude, loc1.longitude, latitude, longitude).compareTo(haversineCalculation(loc1.latitude, loc1.longitude, latitude, longitude)));
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't think the `OrderSpecifier` can do the order you are hoping for since there is a whole function involved and order specifier seems to only be able to take in properties of the entity as ordering descriptors.

Comment: I had something similar but `location.latitude` in `haversinceCalculation` method is `NumberPath` not `int`. Moreover there is no method like `orderBy(double value)`

Comment: After checking the docs a bit more thoroughly I think this isn't possible at the moment. You're trying to create a dynamic order by comparing each queried entry's data and returning a relative double value to use as a comparison. At least OrderSpecifier doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: I saw that too, that's way I'm looking for some way to order my records by distance :)